# jquery mobile 1.4.5 single-page template href querystring ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie to JQM (I use 1.4.5) and my webapp (asp.net C# apache Cordova) contains many separate pages of .cshtml (single-page template) only. I am testing my webapp on a Samsung Galaxy Grand using Android 4.2.2

A. 
I am not sure about my understanding of 'linking pages', even after reading all the JQM docs on this and also after reading up many, many posts on this topic about passing querystring values to another page; mainly because I find that ALMOST ALL the examples are directed towards providing answers for internal pages (Multi-Page template) within a single html page.

So I request some of you JQM experts to confirm or correct the following understanding of mine....

From the JQM docs I understood that

1. I could use in any link (e.g  button),  href="page2.cshtml?par1=1&par2=2"; and JQM will automatically use  Ajax for this link to work.
2. I also understood that use of querystring is always allowed in such cases of different html pages of the same domain and it will work via Ajax automatically ; so long as the attr such as rel="external", data-ajax="false" etc. are not used in the same link.
3. but querystrings are not allowed in case of the internal pages (multi-page template) only....;
4. and if I need to use the above href to link to a page in another domain e.g. www.anotherdomain.com/page2.cshtml?par1=1&par2=2, then  I need to use rel="external".

Are all my above points (that reflect my understanding) CORRECT? KIndly confirm ro please correct me ...

B.
In my app, I find that most of the links work according to my understanding as above, to connect to different pages in the same domain; and I assume it happens via Ajax. Is it correct? I am also able to use the querystring params in page2 ( i.e. To-Page).

1. But in one case, though it works, in the To-Page the Panel features do not operate correctly,  unless I introduce rel="external' in the href link !!! I suppose it means it IS NOT AJAX anymore? Also I am unable to find the reason..
2. Further independent of the above topic, I face another issue. The loading time (i.e. Time taken to display the To-Page) varies.

Mostly it is OK, but at times the loading-circle goes on forever.... and I presume it has crashed....??? then If I go back using the back button and come forward again, many times it loads immediately...!!!!!
Any thoughts or suggestions.....?

Thanks in anticipation...
Ratna

Comment: @Gajotres, Thank you for your detailed comments. I will certainly read, understand and follow them; BUT COULD YOU KINDLY TELL ME THE 4 POINTS I HAVE MENTIONED ( to confirm my understanding is ok) ARE CORRECT? So that I can go ahead with further learning from you and other sources, with the confidence that my basic understanding IS CORRECT. Thanks...... –  Ratna 3 mins ago

Comment: @Gajotres, Also I found an answer (perhaps not the proper one!) to My problem in B1 above, Even without rel="external", When I Reload the Page in JQuery it works .. $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "[data-user_page=pagename]", function () {location.reload(); });      IS IT NECESSARY TO RELOAD after an Ajax call via href to another page in the same domain? Kindly help....Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to match your 4 questions. Now regarding your second question. That JavaScript problem is caused because jQuery Mobile has a very specific way of handling JavaScript. It's a rather long theory so take a look at this link:http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/

Comment: You can mail me if you have more questions: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: @Gajotres, Grateful thanks for answering my questions so specifically as requested by me,  .Also for the link on JQM Page handling ...I will make changes as per your guidelines. Thanks for email address...will mail you the status and also for any further queries....Regards ......

Comment: @Gajotres, Writing this comment here to acknowledge the benefits I have gained in resolving many of my above issues & more by reading he wonderfully well-written articles by you on your website. Thanks and Congrats... I wish I had read your articles earlier.... I would have saved a lot of time.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can worry about how to pass attributes from one page to another you need to understand the difference between multi-page and multi-HTML templates.

#### Multi HTML page template

1. Smaller and lighter, each data-role=”page” is inside a separate HTML file and page structure is much more modular.
2. Can become even smaller if every subsequent HTML page is stripped from HEAD content, or anything that isn’t data-role=”page” div. Unfortunately in this case fallback if JavaScript is not supported is out of question.
3. DOM size is relatively small, only first page is permanently loaded into the DOM, any other page will also be loaded into the DOM but at the same time it will also be removed when not used actively, basically each time you move from it.
4. Better fallback if JavaScript is not supported. Works great in desktop browsers after a page refresh, mainly because every HTML page has an existing HEAD content. This also allows your app to behave like normal web app mainly because AJAX can be turned off.

#### Multipage template

1. Since all pages are already loaded, no additional requests are generated for navigating between pages.
2. First load is slower as the file size is larger, but subsequent page navigation is fast, thus making transitions much more smooth. Almost native-like smooth, emphasize on almost.
3. Suitable for relatively smaller applications and situations where you know the capabilities of your target platforms including presence of JavaScript support, thus making it a great solution for a hybrid app. It works much better as a Phonegap app then multi HTML template.
4. The “page” data-role element is required.

More about this topic can be found here: [Multipage template vs Multi HTML template in jQuery Mobile](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)

Now let's talk about how to properly pass data between jQuery Mobile pages.

1. jQuery Mobile uses AJAX by default
2. You can turn off AJAX using rel="external"
3. If you turn off AJAX you will lose almost everything good about jQuery Mobile, including animations. So if you don't want AJAX page handling better find some other responsive framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.
4. If you don't want to use AJAX you can still use querystrings but inside a href or via changePage function.

#### Better querystrings alternatives:

1. Global object.

If you're using AJAX you can simply use a global object(s) to store all of your data.

Something like this:

```
// Store object
var storeObject = {
    parameter1: null,
    parameter2 : null
}
```

2. Access data from the previous page

Again if you're using AJAX you don't need to pass any data because all that data is till in the DOM.

```
// Store object
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(e, data){     
    alert("My name is " + data.prevPage.find('#test-input').val());
});
```

3. Localstorage or Sessionstorage

This solution will work no matter if you use AJAX or not.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#change-page-button', function(){     
        // store some data
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
              localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
              localStorage.lastname="Gaic";            
        }
        // Change page
        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
    });    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
    alert('My name is ' + localStorage.firstname + ' ' + localStorage.lastname);
    // Lets change localStorage data before we go to the next page
    localStorage.firstname="NewFirstNeme";
    localStorage.lastname="NewLastName";    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#third', function(){       
    alert('My name is ' + localStorage.firstname + ' ' + localStorage.lastname);
});
```

4. Send data through changePage function or via href

   ```
   // Send
   $.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true});
   ```

   or

   ```
   <a href="second.html?paremeter=123" data-role="button">Send parameter</a>
   ```

   receive that same data:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
       var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
       parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
       alert(parameter);
   });
   ```

If you need more information about this solutions including working examples find them here: [Passing data between jQuery Mobile pages](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)

Several methods mentioned here are deprecated (still usable) in the version 1.4. Though you don't need to worry about that, almost everything here will be unusable in version 1.5. This new version will overhaul jQuery Mobile from the bottom to the top.

### Update

1. Yes, you can use any such link and jQuery Mobile will use AJAX. If you take a look at my previous examples you will find a working one.
2. If you want AJAX you CAN'T use rel="external", data-ajax="false" though stringquerys will work in bot cases.
3. Correct they will only work in multi-HTML template. Though there used to be a 3rd party plugin that allowed this to work with multi-page template but I don't think it works with newer jQuery Mobile versions.
4. Correct, if you want to link external page you need to use rel="external".